# Pyhon.exe - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: python

When I try to run python.exe on my computer with Windows 8, I get the following error:

> Python.exe - Entry Point Not Found
>
> The Procedure entry point ?terminate@@YAXXZ could not be located in
>   the dynamic link library C:\Program Files\Python3.5\python.exe.

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe add C:\Program Files\Python3.5\ to the path environment variable, i don't know

Comment: The error doesnt say on what dll the entry point wasnt found?